# What JSON editor am I using in Eclipse?

Tags: json, eclipse

I have a Eclipse Neon installation that I didn't put together by myself. File extension .json is mapped (by File Associations) to something listed there as "JS Editor". Is there a *structured* way to find out what plugin/feature/component/module (in what version) is providing this editor?

This example is about the JSON editor. But it happened to me before that I was guessing and googling about what tool in Eclipse I am actually using. So I would be interested if there is a somewhat more structured approach to this kind of problem.

Comment: If you understand Eclipse plugin extension points you can search the installed editor extension points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Plug-in Spy to determine what plug-in is contributing any UI component, including an editor. Place the cursor in the editor and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open the spy. It looks like this:

[image]

In some Eclipse packages it's automatically included, but if the keyboard shortcut doesn't work then you'll have to install it. [Here](http://jmini.github.io/blog/2016/2016-09-16_eclipse_plugin_spy.html) are some instructions.